# [Could not update: Desired iteration is not in project scope]

Tags: rally

We have been creating TestSet with using Rally API code
for almost 3 years but recently about 2 days ago we started getting
exception.

java.lang.Exception: Failed to Create TestSet [Could not update: Desired iteration is not in project scope]

Code I am using to create TestSet

CreateRequest createTSRequest = new CreateRequest("testset", newTestSet);
CreateResponse createTSResponse = restApi.create(createTSRequest);

Comment: You're creating test sets without an iteration?  Or is there more to your code example?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly an issue with the timeboxes. There could be a duplicate iteration or one that is mis-spelled that is causing some grief. Remove or fix the offending timebox (iteration) and try again. Timeboxes are unique for each project in Rally.